# How to set up a robots.txt file to stop some pages showing in my WordPress theme?

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a WordPress theme and have deployed to production, but some of the pages have no content because currently the page content is not ready. That's the reason I want to use robots.txt for "no content pages".

If anyone has experience here, then please can you help me out?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but "robots.txt" is only here to prevent bots like google from referencing some pages/files, it won't prevent users from acceeding those pages

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it via Robots.txt, then create Robots.txt file in your root directory (where you can see wp-content, wp-admin folders) with this code:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /page
```

But also you can just save a page as a draft in the WP dashboard.

Also you can configure Yoast SEO plugin to noindex your page by search engines, [instruction](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/how-do-i-noindex-urls/).

Comment: ---I can't  save page as a draft because I am also using that as a parent so I want to add robots.txt file

Comment: Where I have to add  this code User-Agent: *
Disallow: /contact-us